# Defining environment for enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I often write

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item [\textbf{1}]
\item [\textbf{2}]
.
.
.
\end{enumerate}
```

but is there a way to get `\item [\textbf{1}]` automatically by just putting `\item`? (I don't want to set a `\newcommand`, I just want that everytime I put `\item` yield me a new number in the style `\textbf{number}`.)

Comment: Look at the 'enumitem' package.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*, font=\bfseries}
```

or

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\arabic*, ref=\arabic*}
```

if you want bold labels at the `first level`  of `enumerate` for the whole document, or  just load `enumitem` and use this for specific environment:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*, font=\bfseries]
   % or [label=\bfseries\arabic*, ref=\arabic*]
\item first item
\item second item
………………
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: It's probably better to add `ref=\arabic*`

Comment: @egreg: Why that? Isn't it automatic?

Comment: No, by default `enumitem` sets the `ref` value equal to `label`

Comment: @egreg; I see. There's also the solution `font=` which affects only the label.

Answer (score 1):

Using the enumitem package, `\usepackage{enumitem}`:

[image]

If you need this behavior locally you can directly insert in the options to `enumerate` the specifications of your labels. If you need it global, then set in the preamble the same as Bernard's answer, `\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\arabic*}`. You can remove or leave the dot as required or add spaces where needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[{\bfseries 1.}]
  \item some item 1
  \item some item 2
  \item some item 3
  \item some item 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This approach is particularly easy if you don't want to remember names, e.g.,

```
[\bfseries 1.] % for Arabic numbers
[\bfseries I.] % for Capital Roman 
[\bfseries A.] % for Capital alphanumeric, ...etc.
```

Comment: Note you can have the same syntax with `enumitem`, if you load it with the `shortlabels` option.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create a new environment to do what you want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{mylist}
{\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}]}
{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{mylist}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `\newlist`? Also, see the comments on Bernard's answer.